# open new window with php code after form submits results

Tags: php, forms, validation, popup, window

here is the script that i been working on , it is supposed to integrate user and pass when opened

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name']; // contain name of person
$pass = $_POST['pass']; // Email address of sender 
$link = window.open(https://secure.brosix.com/webclient/?nid=4444&user=$name&pass=$pass&hideparams=1 'width=710,height=555,left=160,top=170');

echo $link;

?>
```

am i doing this right, i want to open a pop up windows after the user submits the form to the php code but i always get an error.

Comment: Are you printing the javascript out inside a script tag?

Comment: still the same results it opens another tab and displays "window.open ......170)" as text even with script tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name']; // contain name of person
$pass = $_POST['pass']; // Email address of sender 
$link = "<script>window.open('https://secure.brosix.com/webclient/?    nid=4510&user=$name&pass=$pass&hideparams=1', 'width=710,height=555,left=160,top=170')</script>";

echo $link;

?>
```

**Additional Note**

You should consider using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) which can load webpages as a whole in a popup window using iframes. There are other options as well feel free to explore!

Comment: Of course, you'll probably be caught out by popup blockers if you're opening a window that's not a direct result of a user action.

Comment: insted of opening a window it just displays this on the browser "window.open('https://secure.brosix.com/webclient/?nid=4510&user=user&pass=pass&hideparams=1', 'width=710,height=555,left=160,top=170')"

Comment: The OP was talking about some error. My solution will get rid of the error. If the worry is about popup blocker then use `css` to create `Models` as in `Twitter Bootstrap`

Comment: still the same results it opens another tab and displays "window.open ......170)" as text

Comment: @Link There was a typo in `<script>` it was spelled `<scipt>` before.. It should work now.. But as @Cody said it is blocked by popup blocker! you need to find another solution to get around it.

Comment: It wont get blocked if you are using fancybox, shadowbox etc.. Did you try that ?

Comment: If yo have problems in using fancybox post it as a new question.

Comment: cool no problem at all!! i'll inform you when i integrate it to my website!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put quotes and the  tag around $link's value.

```
$link = "<script>window.open(\"https://secure.brosix.com/webclient/?nid=4444&user=$name&pass=$pass&hideparams=1width=710,height=555,left=160,top=170'\")</script>";
```

Comment: still the same results it opens another tab and displays "window.open ......170)" as text

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use php you just create submit button with specific id and then tell jquery to trigger new tab when submit

```
<form id="itemreport_new" type="post" action="">
          <input id="submit2" type="submit" value="show"  target=_blank   />
</form>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#submit2').click(function() {
                 $('#itemreport_new').attr('target','_blank');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>";
$name = $_POST['name']; // CONTAIN NAME OF PERSON
$pass = $_POST['pass']; // ANY DETAIL OF PERSON
$link = "<script>window.open('https://google.co.in')</script>";
echo $link;
```

Comment: You never  used the variables in the link. Thus it explained nothing.  It should have been like:
$link = 'https://google.co.in' . '?name='. $name.'&pass='.$pass;.  Then:
?>
<script>
    window.open('<?php echo $link;?>');
 </script>
<?php