# submitting form don't go as expected

Tags: php, forms, get

I didn't even know how to search for this, but I tried anyways and found nothing. If it's already answered, I give my apologize.
I have this form:

```
<form>
<div style="width:140px;float:left">Nro Socio: <input type="text" id="legajo" name="legajo" size="10" /></div>
<div style="width:200px;float:left">Nombres: <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" size="22" /></div>
<div style="width:200px;float:left">Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" size="22" /></div>
<div style="width:50px;float:left"><input type="submit" id="srch" name="srch" value="Buscar" onclick="offen()" /></div>
</form>
```

Where offen() goes:

```
function offen()
{
$sid = document.getElementById('legajo').value;
$nom = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
$ap = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
if ($sid == "" && $nom == "" && $ap == "") alert ("No se ha ingresado ningún parametro de búsqueda");
else var wnd=window.open('../php/srchSoc.php?sid='+$sid+'&nom='+$nom+'&ap='+$ap,'mywindow',
'width=680,height=350,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0');
}
```

Why I do this instead of using target="_blank" or "_new"? Because I need this to be popup like, and I found no way to make it happen with the form itself.

The page srchSoc.php does some query, and if the resulting rows is just 1, automatically sets opener location to the same page, but with a $_GET value. i.e: '..site/bSoc.php turns' to '..site/bSoc.php?s=1'

Instead, I'm getting that '..site/bSoc.php' turns to '..site/bSoc.php?legajo=&nombre=&apellido=' Just like the form fields names.

Function where I set opener location on srchSoc.php goes like this:

```
<script>window.opener.location='../files/bSoc.php?soc=".$row['c_socio']."';
 window.close();</script>
```

Where $row['c_socio'] is a column of the query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the normal form submission. Change the form submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" id="srch" name="srch" value="Buscar" onclick="offen(); return false;" />
```

`return false` prevents the submit button from submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using

```
<form method="get" action="fileyouwanttogo.php">
```

Comment: Because it opens a new tab, and I want it to be popup-like, with a new customized size window.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand that right then. Here is a post of what you are looking for i think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291523/open-new-window-with-php-code-after-form-submits-results

Comment: That could work, but I'd rather not start using something I don't know, like fancybox, because I don't have much time to do this.

Another thing I forgot to tell is that if I remove the `<form>`, everything works correctly, but it doesn't allow me to submit with 'enter' from the keyboard.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes it way easier. Just search for the enter charachter and if that is pressed then also run the `javascript` function. Not very fancy, but it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I know, i did not understand his question and thought this would fix his whole problem. Then i helped him in the comments to the right answer. What is the problem? @LoganWayne