# window.open() works in html file, but not in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, window.open

**Never mind, guys.  Thanks for your input.  I had another bit of JS grabbing id="btn" because I reused this code from another part of the project.  This is good and working code.**

I have this code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function windowOpen(url) {
  window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'width=350, height=450, top=200, left=500'); return false;
}; </script>
```

and this code down somewhere in the body:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"windowOpen('http://www.abcdef.com')\" title=\"Pop-out\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-new-window\"></i></a>" 
?>
```

I've tried it with and without php syntax on both html and php files.  The html file always works and the php never does.
Any ideas?  Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you running the files? HTML and PHP both i mean , Did u make sure to run it on Apache Server

Comment: Maybe try to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291523/open-new-window-with-php-code-after-form-submits-results).

Comment: I've tried it from a local XAMPP installation as well as on two different web servers.  Same results.

Comment: Just try viewing source code and verify if the php is returning exactly what you require.

Comment: Btw, can you comment the complete URL of the php you are executing? It should be something like `http://localhost/myscript.php`

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with PHP? Did it throw any error?

Comment: @MeganFox, there were no PHP errors, it was just reloading the page.

Comment: Does your browser console say anything? JS errors perhaps?

Comment: @Manikiran Thanks for reminding me to check console.  Another bit of JS was being executed on the element because of id="btn" which I had borrowed from another part of the project.  I took that out and the code worked as expected.

Comment: I copied your code and was running on my local server and its working fine . I think there are some JQuery issues or JavaScript errors occurring , Try enabling the Inspect element panel to track it .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this...

```
<?PHP
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function windowOpen(url) {
  window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'width=350, height=450, top=200, left=500'); return false
}; 
</script>
<a data-rel=\"collapse\" href=\"#\" id=\"btn\" onclick=\"windowOpen('http://www.abcdef.com')\" title=\"Pop-out\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-new-window\"></i></a>
";
?>
```

I think your problem is that windowOpen() method isn't being called since it doesn't know what that method is. But if you place it in the same 'file' it should be able to find and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, guys. Thanks for your input. I had another bit of JS grabbing id="btn" because I reused this code from another part of the project. The edited code above is good.

The page would reload instead of opening a new window because of this other JS function.